# Static "constants" in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, constants

I have come across the built-in static const Vector3D.Z_AXIS. It is supposed to be = (0,0,1). Then I did this and was socked:

```
        trace(Vector3D.Z_AXIS);
        Vector3D.Z_AXIS.x = 100;
        trace(Vector3D.Z_AXIS);

result:
Vector3D(0, 0, 1)
Vector3D(100, 0, 1)
```

So, I broke Flash. Any code after this point expecting Vector3D.Z_AXIS to be the correct value has suddenly stopped working.

I know I can clone the value but still, how can I know I am cloning the correct one? Shouldn't they have provided a static **function** like:

```
static public function Z_Axis():Vector3D {
    return new Vector3D(0,0,1);
}
```

Gosh. I mish C++'s **const...const** declaration.

Comment: This has to be a bug. Unless there is something I am missing. It should have been setup as a GET function. Unless the way CONST is implemented is to only restrict the specific variable value verse any associated properties of said variable value.

Comment: @C.Parcell: It is a constant, therefore it cannot be change to a different object, but that doesn't mean its properties are also constant. Hence the wish to be able to handle it the way c++ does: specify separately if the pointer and/or the values being pointed to are constant. I don't think this is a bug.

Comment: The "bug" is that the API provides a Vector3D named "Z_AXIS" which can be altered at will. They should have named it "Z_AXIS_PLEASE_PLEASE_READ_ONLY".

Comment: @null is correct. Z_AXIS is constant but that doesn't mean its properties are constant. You can test this like so: `const vec = new Vector3D();`
`vec.x = 100;`
`trace(vec); //Vector3D(100, 0, 0)`
`vec = new Vector3D(); //Illegal assignemnt error`

Comment: @BillKotsias: It's understandable that the possibility to change the axis is undesired if it doesn't fit your use case. It is, however not generally true that an axis never changes. So if the axis behaved the way you currently want it to, the next guy would complain about the impossibility to change the axis properties (say over time) or swap the axis entirely (change coordinate space).